# Created a modelform in django, primary key is missing

Tags: django, python-3.x, primary-key, modelform

I created a modelform in django, but the primary key field is missing in the browser. Where is it? How can I get it to appear. Let me know if you need more code than what I have below.

**view.py**

```
import autocomplete_light
import datetime

from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response, RequestContext
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.utils.timezone import utc
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from error_tracking.models import Incident

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from error_tracking.forms import IncidentForm


@login_required
def search_incidents(request):

    # form validation
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = autocomplete_light.IncidentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = IncidentForm()

    # grabbing all OPEN incidents
    incident_list = Incident.objects.filter(open = 'True').order_by('-incident_date_time_reported')

    return render(request, 'search_incidents.html', { 
        'incident_list' : incident_list,
        'user' : request.user,
        'form' : form
    })
```

**forms.py**

```
import autocomplete_light
from django.forms import ModelForm

from error_tracking.models import Incident

autocomplete_light.register(Incident, search_fields=['incident_id'])

class IncidentForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Incident
        fields = ['incident_id', 'user_id', 'equipment_id', 'incident_category', 'incident_date_time_reported', 'incident_date_time_occurred', 'description']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone


class Manufacturer(models.Model):
        manufacturer = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.manufacturer

        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural="Manufacturer"

class Equipment_Category(models.Model):
        equipment_category = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
                return self.equipment_category

        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural="Equipment Category"

class Equipment(models.Model):
        product_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
        manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer)
        equipment_category = models.ForeignKey(Equipment_Category)
        validated= models.BooleanField(default=True)
        in_service_date = models.DateTimeField('in service date', default=timezone.now)

        def __str__(self):
               return self.product_id

        class Meta:
               verbose_name_plural="Equipment"

class Incident_Category(models.Model):
        incident_category = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
        description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

        def __str__(self):
               return self.incident_category

        class Meta:
                verbose_name_plural="Incident Category"

class Incident(models.Model):
       incident_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
       incident_date_time_reported = models.DateTimeField('incident reported', default=timezone.now)
       user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
       incident_date_time_occurred = models.DateTimeField('incident occurred', default=timezone.now)
       clinical_sample = models.BooleanField(default=True)
       number_of_clinical_samples = models.IntegerField(default=0)
       sample_id_numbers = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       equipment_id = models.ForeignKey(Equipment)
       incident_category = models.ForeignKey(Incident_Category)
       technician = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       action_taken = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       open = models.BooleanField(default=True)

       def __str__(self):
               return self.incident_id

       class Meta:
               verbose_name_plural="Incident"
```

**search_incidents.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<br>
<p>Not only have you successfully logged in, you have also made it to the Search Incidents page using html templates</p>
<br><br>


<!--incident_id-->
<!--CAPA number-->
<!--Date From To-->
<!--Creator-->
<!--Status-->
<!--Category-->
<!--Equipment ID-->
<!--Search Description-->
<!--error_tracking.views.search_usernames-->

<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>


<div id="table-wrapper" style="overflow:auto; height:600px;">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-1">ID</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Open</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Created At</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Category</th>
            <th class="col-md-7">Description</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {% for incident in incident_list %}
        <tr>
            <td class="col-md-1">{{ incident.incident_id }}</td>
            <td class="col-md-1">{{ incident.open }}</td>
            <td class="col-md-2">{{ incident.incident_date_time_reported }}</td>
            <td class="col-md-1">{{ incident.incident_category }}</td>
            <td class="col-md-7">{{ incident.description}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: If its missing in the browser please show your HTML Template and the corresponding view.

Comment: absolutely. here it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading some [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L793), I do not think you could ever, even accidentally, expose an [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#autofield) to the user:

> ```
> def pk_is_not_editable(pk):
>         return ((not pk.editable) or (pk.auto_created or isinstance(pk, AutoField))
> ```

If you really want to expose the PK to your user ( I don't know why you would like to do this) you have to expose it explicitly both on the model and the form as an [`IntegerField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/fields/#integerfield) or `ModelForm` will exclude it for you:

```
import autocomplete_light
from django.forms import ModelForm, IntegerField

from error_tracking.models import Incident

autocomplete_light.register(Incident, search_fields=['incident_id'])

class IncidentForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Incident
        fields = ['incident_id', 'user_id', 'equipment_id', 'incident_category', 'incident_date_time_reported', 'incident_date_time_occurred', 'description']
    incident_id = IntegerField()

class Incident(models.Model):
       incident_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
       incident_date_time_reported = models.DateTimeField('incident reported', default=timezone.now)
       user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
       incident_date_time_occurred = models.DateTimeField('incident occurred', default=timezone.now)
       clinical_sample = models.BooleanField(default=True)
       number_of_clinical_samples = models.IntegerField(default=0)
       sample_id_numbers = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       equipment_id = models.ForeignKey(Equipment)
       incident_category = models.ForeignKey(Incident_Category)
       technician = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       description = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       action_taken = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
       open = models.BooleanField(default=True)

       def __str__(self):
               return self.incident_id

       class Meta:
               verbose_name_plural="Incident"
```

Comment: I wanted to automatically assign an id to an incident and would like the user to use the id in a search later on. Does that make sense? Is there a better way to do it then expose pk?